# HttpBrowserCapabilities.Crawler property .NET

Tags: .net, web-crawler

How does the HttpBrowserCapabilities.Crawler property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332775(VS.71).aspx) work?  I need to detect a partner's custom crawler and this property is returning false.

Where/How can I add his user agent so that this property will return true?  Any other way outside of creating my own user agent detecting mechanism?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all driven by the default browsercaps declarations that are part of the .NET framework.

To setup this specific crawler, you would need to add a custom browserCaps section to your web.config to identify it as a crawler.

The MSDN documentation on how to go about this is pretty well documented, [here is a link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk9az15a.aspx)

Comment: unfortunately, now a dead link :(

Answer (score 2):

HttpBrowserCapabilities is populated from a set of *.browser files in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Browsers. You can add your own file in ~/App_Browsers/ with the details of your custom crawler. The schema is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228122.aspx). Basically it contains a regular expression to match against the User-Agent header and a collection of property values.